# Nice way of splitting up Node.js code over multiple files

Tags: node.js

I currently have code similar to:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('ping', function (data) {
    socket.emit("ping", data);
  });
});
```

I want to seperate:

```
socket.on('ping', function (data) {
   socket.emit("ping", data);
});
```

into a seperate file but that it is still able to use the socket variable, im using a lot of socket.on functions with in the 'connection' function and was wondering if there is anyway of splitting these sub function over multiple files. something like:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  require('otherFunctions.js');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work I think:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', require('otherFunctions.js').socketConnection);
```

And then in `otherFunctions.js` just export `socketConnection`:

```
exports.socketConnection = function(socket) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: why the .socketConnection behind the require? And how can I include multiple files?

Comment: The `.socketConnection` would be the name of the function you've exported in `otherFunction.js`. You're using it in-place of your anonymous function, so it will take in a `socket` object.

Comment: Nice I will still have to try this (tomorrow) but how would I require multiple files?

Comment: It is currently saying pool is not defined, how do I add pool as a variable to the require?

Comment: I'm not sure what "pool" is. You can 'require' whatever you need as usual at the top of `otherFunctions.js`. You can require as many files as you like, or define all your functions in one file. If you only want the one function in your file you can even do `module.exports = function(socket)` and then drop the `.socketConnection` bit.